# Handling normals with indexed geometry

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, game-engine, directx-11

Is it possible to use Vertex Buffer with Index Buffer and apply normals? It seems that normal is more like an attribute of a face, than an attribute of a vertex. F.e. in a cube, each vertex have 3 normals, depending on the face.

Is there a smart way of using normals with indexed geometry? Or do I have to construct only Vertex Buffer and stop using index buffer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Normals are vertex attributes; you need to duplicate the vertices where your mesh isn't supposed to be smooth. (In a cube, each corner will have three vertices, one for each "face normal".)

Comment: @molbdnilo so you're saying that in this case I would have 24 vertices instead of only 8, right? Ok, and how about the case where i have for example complex human face mesh?

Comment: Human faces are smooth, like most things in nature.

Comment: Ok, so how do you see the difference? How do you decide if you would like have "smooth" or "sharp" setting for handling normals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and even better to use Indexed Faces. All `Normals` will be stored for each `Vertex` like `Positions`.

For Cube there will be more Vertices comparing with no-normal model. But For Sphere there will be the same vertices amount (common Normal for adjacent Faces).

It is better to calculate normals when you know the source geometry otherwise result could be not reliable. For example smooth Cylinder and Prism could have same positions.

Comment: Lets assume that I already have normals (f.e. from OBJ file in blender). Without normals, I would have 8 verices and 24 indices. How can i use Indexed Faces in this example? Using one Normal per Vertex would be incorrect, since it would have been shaded differently depending on the face.

Comment: You'll have many Vertices with same Position and different Normals. If noramls goes not with position (like in .OBJ) you will need to find all unique pairs of PositionIndex and NormalIndex.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. So basically Cube is a bad example, since there will be exaclty 24 unique vertices, right? :P Sphear would behave better, is this correct?

Comment: For memory usage per position sphere is the best :) For complex geometry you will have both one vertex for some positions and many vertices for another.
For .obj the trick is to find unique `position and normal` combinations. Thus you will reduce memory usage (vertices count).